# ReportViewer no aparece en el formulario

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Agrege las referencias, lo agrege al cuadro de herramientas y al arrastrarlo sobre el formulario no aparece y queda como aparece en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alejandro, bienvenido a SOes. Si pudieras poner el código que estas utilizando para tu proyecto seria muy bueno. Te recomiendo ver el enlace [mcve], para mas información. Saludos!

Comment: Que versión de Visual Studio estas usando? como agreagste las referencias?

Comment: A mi me passa lo mismo, alguen sabe como resolver el problema?
gracias
se me olvidava, estoy usando visual studio 2017

Comment: A mi también me ocurre y también uso Visual Studio 2017. La única alternativa que he encontrado para mostrarlo en el formulario fue mediante código, pero es una pena que no se pueda ver en modo diseño. A ver si alguien tiene los conocimientos suficientes como para decirnos como hacerlo. Gracias.